# How to render another models form on another page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Ok so Ive looked around at many answers posted on stackoverflow and many other sites because I know that this is a commonly asked question but I just cant seem to get it and would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. What Im trying to achieve here is really simple, Im trying to render a new form from another model, **Post** into my homepage, which is another controller that I created. So basically in my homepage it shows a list of all the recent **Post** that were created by users. Furthermore I wanted to user to be able to directly add a new Post from the homepage. Right now I have it displaying however clicking on the submit button does absolutely nothing.

**Here is the form for POST**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <%= image_tag @post.user.avatar.url(:post_pic), class:"img-thumbnail" %>
    <%= @post.user.name %>

    <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
      <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :content %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :content %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Here is my homepage controller**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
        @posts = Post.all
        @post = current_user.posts.build

    else
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    @post.save
  end

 private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :content, :avatar)
  end
end
```

**Lastly my homepage index**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h1>Home#index</h1>
        <p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>

        <%= render 'posts/form' %>

        <% @posts.each do |post|%>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <%= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:post_pic), class:"img-thumbnail" %>
                        <%= post.user.name %>
                    </h3>
                </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <%= post.content %></br></br>

                <% if post.avatar.file? %>
                <%= image_tag post.avatar.url(:test), class:"img-thumbnail" %></br>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  get 'users/index'

  get 'users/show'

  root 'home#index'

  devise_for :users
```

Comment: please show us your routes, `form_for(@post)` will send the form to `/posts`

Answer (score 0):

So, you're doing like saving post data using **another Controller(Home)** instead of **Post Controller**, right?

Your **partial form** for post uses:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
// @post generated url (/posts)
// will look for create method in POST Controller
```

I suggest to put your saving codes in proper controller(posts), so you will prevent **code duplication/redundancy**.

**TIP**:
If you are worrying about redirection from Home view or from Posts view,

you can use **params[:controller]** for ***checking where the request came from***,  by just using **if statement**.

Finally, you can **redirect it to proper page after saving**.